# Postgres, how to access all the tables in a database iteratively, subquery?

Tags: postgresql

Hi Postgres community :D

I am trying to read contents of tables to grasp the picture of them.
So, my question is:
How could it be done to display all the head of tables inside a database giving same result as below naive tidious queries.
I guess there must be a fancy way of just one line query to do this..
Please help me out!

```
# naive
SELECT * FROM mytable0001;
SELECT * FROM mytable0002;
SELECT * FROM mytable0003;
...
SELECT * FROM mytable9999;


# wannabe
SELECT * FROM foo (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables) AS foo limit 5;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do all tables have the same structure? Why isn't that just one table? And what is the actual problem you are trying to solve with that? This doesn't really make sense to me

Comment: Thanks for your comment! First the tables have different columns. Well, I am a beginner of database and just several days passed to start Postgres. The problem I am facing is very clear, I think. I just want to see what the contents are inside bunch of tables in a database. I am trying to analyze the contents of all the tables. But there are too many to type by hand SELECT queries for each tables. I want to find a nice way, if it were a linux command then: head ./* I think this linux command anology explains the situation :)

Comment: If the tables have different columns, then you can't get a single result from all tables. Typically [GUI clients](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients) will make it much easier to quickly look at the data in the tables.

Comment: Ah.. I see.. GUI I am gonna try it ! But is it possible to use FOR loop like python script: for table in database: SELECT * FROM table limit 5;

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use psql CLI and \gexec command.
With following input:

```
select format('select * from %s;',tablename) 
from pg_tables
where tablename like 'table%'
\gexec
```

You get in one go:

```
select format('select * from %s;',tablename) 
from pg_tables
where tablename like 'table%'
select * from table0001;
 c1 |   c2    
----+---------
  1 | table 1
(1 row)

select * from table0002;
 c1 |   c2    
----+---------
  1 | table 2
  2 | table 2
(2 rows)

select * from table0003;
 c1 |   c2    
----+---------
  1 | table 3
  2 | table 3
  3 | table 3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pifor ! These queries work and solved my problem. This is exactly what I looking for : D